# Filter/search and show icons only

Tags: java, html, css

I'm going crazy trying to show only the icons from the search box.

http://www.rsbdylgy.lucusvirtual.es/main.htm
(you can see the 'search' script in the same html code)

Typing "one" = I need to show the "one" icon

Typing "six" = I need to show the "+" icon

In other words, I need to apply 2 filters from the HTML:

```
title="FILTER1"
<li><a href="#" target="_blank">FILTER2</a></li>
```

I am not able to solve something so simple, I hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
function checkEntry() {
    var value = $("#myInput").val().toLowerCase();

    $("#content1 a.card").filter(function() {
        if (this.dataset.toggle === "dropdown") {
           // This filters the drop-down links as well, but you may
           //  just want to decide whether or not to show the "+" card
           $(this).parent().find('a:not(.card)').filter(function() {
               $(this).toggle(this.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
           })
        }
        else {
            $(this).toggle(this.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
        }
    });
};
```

as your 'keyup' event handler.

The way you're doing it with your selector is selecting too many elements and looking at the text() function of those, very few have the values you would want.

I always find it useful to use the browser's embedded developer tools, so you can see what's happening.

Your selector is selecting all of these elements:

```
>$("#content1 *")
w.fn.init(23) [div.numbers, a.card, img, a.card, img, a.card, img, a.card, img, a.card, img, div.dropdown, a.card.dropdown-toggle, img, ul.dropdown-menu, li, a, li, a, li, a, li, a, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
```

Looking at just one of the ones you'd actually want, shows that text() is not getting the information you want that's in the 'title' attribute:

```
>$($("#content1 *")[1]).text()
""
```

Comment: I have not been able to solve it, it's more difficult than it seems.
Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Did you try just swapping out
'var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();..' in your script tag with the code snippet above?